# What does ArC mean?

Tags: quarkus

The [CDI or ArC reference documentation of Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference) does not even mention the name ArC, except in package names.

Is ArC an acronym? Does it mean anything except *the CDI flavour of Quarkus*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact, the full name is ArC DI and it's a reference to [arc welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_welding). As you probably know, [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/) is the CDI reference implementation and an open source project sponsored by Red Hat.